# How to conditionally display HTML in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show specific HTML in my page depending of IF conditions, I have a static variable to determine the status of the page and what to show, the problem is that after the first page load, no more html is rendered.

This is one of my if :

```
   @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 2)
            {
                <text>
            <div id="thirdDiv" data-step="3" class="no-show">
                <div class="span6">
```

I have a button to change the value of the global variable like :

```
<form  action="UploadPhoto/setNext" method="post">
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">siguiente</button>
                            </form>
```

And it goes to this controller's method :

```
public ActionResult setNext()
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.Step < 3)
            {
                GlobalVariables.Step  += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                RedirectToAction("AdjustDots", "VirtualTesterController");
            }
            return View("Load");
        }
```

**UPDATE FULL CODE :**

```
    @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 1)
    {
   <div id="firstDiv" data-step="1" >
        <!-- SUBIR FOTO -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="md-your-data">
                    <div class="hd">
                    <h2>1. @ViewBag.Strings["completarDatos"]</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bd">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class='selectBox'>
                                <span class='selected' id="ageSelected">@ViewBag.Strings["rangoEdad"]</span>
                                    <span class='selectArrow'></span>
                                    <div class="selectOptions">
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Option 1</span>
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Option 2</span>
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Option 3</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class='selectBox'>
                                <span class='selected' id="skinToneSelected">@ViewBag.Strings["tonoPiel"]</span>
                                    <span class='selectArrow'></span>
                                    <div class="selectOptions">
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Option 1</span>
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Option 2</span>
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Option 3</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class='selectBox'>
                                <span class='selected' id="skinTypeSelected">@ViewBag.Strings["tipoPiel"]</span>
                                    <span class='selectArrow'></span>
                                    <div class="selectOptions">
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Option 1</span>
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Option 2</span>
                                        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Option 3</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ft">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <div class="md-upload-photo">
                    <div class="hd">
                    <h2>2. @ViewBag.Strings["SubiTuFoto"]</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pictureDiv" class="bd">
                        <div id="dropPicture" class="photo-cont no-photo" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event)">
                            <div id="picDiv"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="ft">
                        <div class="file-input-wrapper">
                            <button class="btn-file-input">@ViewBag.Strings["subir"]</button>
                            <input id='file' class="btn-file" type='file' accept="image/*" onchange="manageFilePicker(event)" />
                        </div>

                        @using (Html.BeginForm("setNext", "UploadPicture"))
                        {
                             <button class="btn"  type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
                <div class="md-model-photo">
                    <div class="hd">
                    <h2>@ViewBag.Strings["Elegirfotodemodelo"] </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bd">
                        <ul id="modelsList">
                            <li>
                                <img src="~/Content/images/imagen-modelo-upload.png" alt="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="~/Content/images/imagen-modelo-upload.png" />
                                <img src="~/Content/images/imagen-modelo-upload.png" alt="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="~/Content/images/imagen-modelo-upload.png" alt="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="~/Content/images/imagen-modelo-upload.png" alt="" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ft">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- END SUBIR FOTO -->
       </div>
    }


      @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step > 2)
    {
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- BEGIN MANAGE PHOTO -->

        <div id="secondDiv" data-step="2" class="no-show">
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="md-adjust-photo-img">
                    <div class="bd">
                        <div class="img-cont">
                            <img src="~/Content/images/img-modelo.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 2)
             {
            <div id="thirdDiv" data-step="3" class="no-show">
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="md-adjust-photo-data step-1">
                        <div class="hd">
                        <h3>4. @ViewBag.Strings["encuadrarFoto"]</h3>
                        <p>@ViewBag.Strings["encuadrarFotoDesc"]</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ft">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("setPrevious", "UploadPicture"))
                            {
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Atras</button>
                            }
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("setNext", "UploadPicture"))
                            {
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             }
             @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 3)
             {
            <div id="fourthDiv" data-step="4" class="no-show">
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="md-adjust-photo-data step-2">
                        <div class="hd">
                <h3>5. @ViewBag.Strings["brilloYcontraste"]</h3>
                <p>@ViewBag.Strings["brilloYcontrasteDesc"]</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bd">
                            <div class="col">
                    <span>@ViewBag.Strings["brightness"]</span>
                                <div class="tone-bar">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                    <span>@ViewBag.Strings["contrast"]</span>
                                <div class="tone-bar">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ft">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("setPrevious", "UploadPicture"))
                            {
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Atras</button>
                        }
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("setNext", "UploadPicture"))
                            {
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                        }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             }
        </div>
    </div>

    }
```

Comment: You should probably look into using a view model and passing that variable down with it ...

Comment: There is not a problem passing the variable, since while debugging I can see that the condition is evaluated and that the variable value's changed, the thing is, the html inside the the IF statement does not render

Comment: @MaG3Stican can you post your full HTML - struggling to see where the problem lies with such limited code. FWIW not a great idea to use `static` properties in a web application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend you make use of partial views for your *selective* HTML - it would clean up your code. So imagine that's what I have done for you here, this gives you purely the logic

```
@if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 1)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("Step1")
}

@if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step > 2)
{
    // some default HTML here
    @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 2)
    {
        @Html.RenderPartial("Step2")
    }
    @if (WhiteLabel.Controllers.GlobalVariables.Step == 3)
    {
        @Html.RenderPartial("Step3")
    }
}
```

So looking at this purely from a logic POV, for there to be no output `Step` needs to be `> 3`. Given you are using `static` variable the potential for that to happen is plausible because you have what's known as a *race condition*. If 2 threads (i.e. 2 sessions) attempt to proceed to the next page both will attempt to increment `Step` - where the race condition comes in is

```
// Assume 'Step' is 2 here
// Session A checks first, then Session B - both checks pass
if (GlobalVariables.Step < 3)
{
    // Session A increments first, then Session B
    GlobalVariables.Step += 1; // value is now 4
}
```

On top of that, your application becomes session independent i.e. if 1 user is on Step 3, so is everyone else!

I recommend store your `Step` property in the users `Session`.

Comment: thank you for your comments, regardless, after moving everything to partial views, still the HTML does not get rendered, I just see an empty html body after hitting next which changes the condition of the if

Comment: @MaG3Stican the partial view stuff isn't the problem, that was a suggestion to tidy up your code. The problem is with using a `static` variable. Have you looked at it in the debugger at view level?

Comment: I was using a no-show class accidentally, thank you for your other su ggestions

Comment: @MaG3Stican I assumed the `static` problem wouldn't have been your issue because it would be just you testing it - however, it *is* a problem and you should fix it now before you go any further.

Comment: Speaking of cleaning up the code, I'd use a `switch` rather than a series of `if()`s. And checking if `.Step > 2`, immediately followed by checking `.Step == 2`, is unlikely to do anything. :)

Comment: @DavidLively actually it does, if you look at the OPs code there is HTML that has to be written out if the current step is > 2 then the output is further refined based on whether it's 2/3. Also, personally I would say a switch wouldn't work well here considering the > 2 check - I think an if works fine.

Comment: @James I'm probably missing something here, but since the nested `if(.Step==2) { ... } ` is effectively `if (.Step > 2 && .Step == 2) { ... }`, I'm having trouble seeing *any* circumstance where it would execute. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @DavidLively that was my bad.... The check should be >= 2. As it stands you are correct the > 2 if effectively redundant :)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't going to work. The variable isn't going to persist because the controller is rebuilt on every post back. You have some options, but I think the best would be this; store the value in `Session` so it can be retrieved during post back **and** it's specific to that user's session.

So, in your controller, you might do something like this:

```
var step = Session["step"] == null ? 1 : (int)Session["step"];
step++;
this.ViewBag.Step = step;
Session["step"] = step;
```

And now in your view, instead of checking the static property, leverage the `ViewBag`:

```
(int)ViewBag.Step == 1
```

for example. In fact, since it's `dynamic`, you don't even have to cast:

```
ViewBag.Step == 1
```

or maybe:

```
ViewBag.Step < 3
```

Comment: It's a `static` property.

Comment: As much as your edit is a *better* alternative than using a `static` property, it still isn't really what the problem is.

Comment: @James, yeah I guess I can see that because it is in fact a `static` property. Hmm.